# using lucene create index with web page URL

Tags: lucene

I want to save the URL into field in lucene. I have a problem because firstly I crawled the content of web pages saved them to different name txts. And I saved another txt separately with docid and URL. When I query, it can show the relevant docid and conent. Now I want to display the result with docid and URL.

```
Field Fieldurl=new Field("url",url,Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NO);
```

Comment: Show your code that will add some context to the problem. How is this a programming problem?

Comment: Are you saying you have the url and the content in separate documents?